# Invalid assignment to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node
  {
  int data;
  struct node * next;
  } node;

  int main()
  {
      node * head;
      head->data=5; //crash
  }
```

I don't understand why something like this would crash? I've been working with pointers for a few months but the simplest example seems to have me stumped.

Comment: You need to make `head` point to a `node` object. Currently it doesn't point to anything you can write to.

Comment: Can you give an example? I follow you but any example would help it set in.

Comment: `head` was a place of the write-protect it have pointing to somewhere in memory. E.g `(NULL)->data = 5;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on what **juanchopanza** said in the comment:
Your `node * head;` creates a pointer but it does not point to any valid `node` struct.
You first need to allocate space for that using `malloc`, e.g.:

`node * head = malloc(sizeof(node));`

Also do not forget to `free` at the end of your program, so as to not cause a memory leak:

`free(head);`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I don't know why space allocation flew passed me

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing to anything.

```
 node *head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You are best of checking malloc returns correctly and ensuring you free head when finished

Comment: Please don't cast `malloc` in C

Comment: Thanks @unholysheep just looked it up. I thought it was needed